# laravel SQLSTATE error inserting in wrong table?

Tags: php, insert, laravel-5.6

i am a beginner in laravel, now i have a problem regarding with my inserting in database. The error states that

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myhris_db.description' doesn't exist.
```

Why is it selecting table name description ? i have my table name deduction. Please take a look in my code:

Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Deduction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'deduction';
    protected $primaryKey = 'deduction_id';

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'description' => 'required|max:255|unique:description',
            'note' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'description.unique' => trans('auth.DescriptionTaken'),
            'description.required' => trans('auth.DescriptionRequired'),
            'description.max' => trans('auth.DescriptionMax'),
            'note.required' => trans('auth.NoteRequired'),
            'status.required' => trans('auth.StatusRequired'),
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $deduction = Deduction::create([
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'note' => $request->input('note'),
        'status' => $request->input('status'),
    ]);

    return redirect('admin-deduction')->with('success', trans('usersmanagement.createSuccess'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'description'   =>  'required|max:255|unique:description'
```

`unique:description` means need raws unique in table `description`

[document here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)